# how to parse a variable content and then evaluate a condition based on that , python

Tags: python, logging

I am writing a generic python script which can be run on various system. I am stuck on a condition where i need to check the variable's content. Till now my simple code looks like :

```
log_path = parser.get('default', 'log_path')

# name and location of tar file
tar_file = 'logs.tar.gz'
working_path = os.getcwd()
file_location = os.path.join(working_path,tar_file)

# open conection to s3 and get bucket object
s3_conn = S3Connection()
bucket = s3_conn.get_bucket('smso-eng-log-share')

# make tar.gz
with tarfile.open(tar_file, 'w:gz') as tar:
    tar.add(log_path, arcname='tomcat7')
```

The variable `log_path` is being picked up from a .ini file.

Say the current value of `log_path = /var/log/tomcat7/` then it creates the log tar with name of `tomcat7`.

Now suppose `log_path = /var/log/haproxy/` then it should create with a name '`haproxy`'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `"/var/log/haproxy/".split('/')` or `os.path.split("/var/log/haproxy/")` to get part of path.

See more functions in doc: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

Comment: i am a bit confused , i want to write a condition statement inside the .ini file

`{% else %}
  if /var/log/haproxy/ exists 
    then log_path = /var/log/haproxy/
  elif /var/log/tomcat7 exists 
    then log_path = /var/log/tomcat7/
{% endif %}`

I wanna know if syntax is right?

Comment: it is new problem - create new question.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(log_path))
```

where `log_path` is your variable containing the path name.

Example:

```
>>> log_path = '/var/log/tomcat7/'
>>> os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(log_path))
>>> 'tomcat7'
```